# Define a reusable "repositories" variable into init.gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following `init.gradle` into `$HOME/.gradle`:

```kotlin
settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "my-repo"
                url = uri("some-url")
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv("username")
                    password = System.getenv("password")
                }
            }
            gradlePluginPortal()
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositories {
            maven {
                name = "my-repo"
                url = uri("some-url")
                credentials {
                    username = System.getenv("username")
                    password = System.getenv("password")
                }
            }
            gradlePluginPortal()
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "my-repo"
            url = uri("some-url")
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("username")
                password = System.getenv("password")
            }
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

I do not like that I have to repeat the same repository configuration three times, and I would like to use a variable to define it. So, I tried the following but it does not work:

```kotlin
val repoConfig: RepositoryHandler = {
    maven {
        name = "my-repo"
        url = uri("some-url")
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("username")
            password = System.getenv("password")
        }
    }
    gradlePluginPortal()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories { repoConfig }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositories { repoConfig }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories { repoConfig }
}
```

At the moment, `repoConfig` variable is detecting the wrong type `() -> ???` instead of `RepositoryHandler`, but I am not even sure that `repositories { repoConfig }` statement will work.

Update: I tried the following based on an answer, and I am getting the following error: Type mismatch: inferred type is `RepositoryHandler!.(Any?) -> Unit` but `(RepositoryHandler!.() -> Unit)!` was expected

```kotlin
fun configureRepos(handler: RepositoryHandler) {
    handler.maven {
        name = "my-repo"
        url = uri("some-url")
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("username")
            password = System.getenv("password")
        }
    }
    handler.gradlePluginPortal()
    handler.mavenCentral()
    handler.mavenLocal()
}

settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories { (it: RepositoryHandler) -> configureRepos(it) }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositories { (it: RepositoryHandler) -> configureRepos(it) }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories { (it: RepositoryHandler) -> configureRepos(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a simple method to configure `RepositoryHandler` like follows (for `init.gradle`):

```
def configureRepos(handler) {
    handler.maven {
        name = "my-repo"
        url = uri("some-url")
        credentials {
            username = System.getenv("username")
            password = System.getenv("password")
        }
    }
    handler.gradlePluginPortal()
    handler.mavenCentral()
    handler.mavenLocal()
}

settingsEvaluated { settings ->
    settings.pluginManagement {
        repositories { repos -> configureRepos(repos) }
    }
    settings.dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositories { repos -> configureRepos(repos) }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories { repos -> configureRepos(repos) }
}
```

If you have `init.gradle.kts` it could look something like this:

```
val repositoryHandler = { handler: RepositoryHandler ->
    handler.apply {
        maven {
            name = "my-repo"
            url = uri("some-url")
            credentials {
                username = System.getenv("username")
                password = System.getenv("password")
            }
        }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

settingsEvaluated {
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            repositoryHandler.invoke(this)
        }
    }
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositories {
            repositoryHandler.invoke(this)
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        repositoryHandler.invoke(this)
    }
}
```

Comment: probably this works for groovy dsl, unfortunately it does not for kts one I am using

Comment: Is your `init.gradle` written by gradle in Kotlin? @GiacomoVenturini

Comment: yes, all the build and init.gradle are written using kotlin dsl

Comment: I have updated my answer and added example for `init.gradle.kts` @GiacomoVenturini